# "Li ha mandati in un parco" - analisi grammaticale

Tags: verbs, pronouns, auxiliary-verb, agreement, past-participle

Non capisco perché si usi la forma "mandati" invece di "mandato". Non è semplicemente un passato prossimo?

Comment: Ho visto che hai un'altro account su Italian.SE. Se volessi unificarli, nel "Help Center" si spiega quello che devi fare: "visit the [contact form](http://italian.stackexchange.com/contact) and select ‘I need to merge user profiles’."

Comment: @Charo : Non mi sono accorto. Grazie!